# Expect script to automate login to Eggdrop bot

Tags: debian, telnet, expect, irc, eggdrop

I want to automate a login proces using a Expect script.
The idea is that the Expect script will start telnet and login.
I need this script for my C# client application that im developing.

This will be the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set password [lindex $argv 3]

spawn telnet $ip $port
expect "'^]'."
sleep .1;
send "\r";
expect { "login:" {
    send "$user"
    expect "Password:"
    send "$password";
    interact
send "\r";
expect { "login:" {
    send "$user"
    expect "Password:"
    send "$password";
    interact

  }
   "host: Connection refused"{
    send_user "ERROR:EXITING!"
    exit
  }
}
```

The problem is that i am getting this error:
    Botty (Eggdrop v1.8.0+preinit (C) 1997 Robey Pointer (C) 2010 Eggheads)

```
Please enter your nickname.
Sorry, that nickname format is invalid.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Someone maybe has an idea how to format the user- and password-string so that a eggdrop login sesion via telnet will work?

Comment: Looks like problem with the eggdrop bot. Are you getting this prompt for nickname when do it manually ? If yes, then you have to add it up with `expect` script too.

Comment: You should add `\r` when sending stuff.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn Wow thanks, I will try this as soon as i start working on the project again (its been a few months you see).